# Can neural style transfer work on the image style in this question or is there a better technique?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I've been working with this neural style paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06576v2.pdf
to try and transfer the style from this image to photos of pets. In case you're not familiar with the technique, I'll leave a brief explanation of it at the end.

[image]

After taking the time to understand some of the concepts in the paper I've come to my own conclusion that the method won't work. Here's why I think this:

- The style is not localised/fine-grained enough. If I take a small piece of this image, I might just get a solid color, or two colors separated by a zig-zag boundary. So the first few convolutional layers won't find any characteristics of interest.
- The style depends on *long-distance correlations* (I made that term up). If you follow some of theses zig-zag interfaces with your eyes you'll see that they traverse up to 1/3 of the characteristic size of the image. So bunches of pixels that take up a lot of space are correlated via the style. And from my intuition of CNNs, you can distill lots of pixels into coarser information (like "this is a dog") but you can't really go backwards. I don't think the CNN encodes the required logic to trace out a zig-zag over a long distance.
- The color palette is restricted. I'm not sure why, but my intuition tells me the Neural Style Transfer technique won't be able to produce a restricted color pallet like in the style example. I'm guessing again, that the CNN doesn't encode any logic around the number of colors used.

**So my question is around whether or not the technique could work, and if not, what's a better technique for this problem.**

**(optional read) Summary of deep style transfer**

1. Take a pre-trained model like VGG19.
2. Feed in a photo. For each conv layer you can reconstruct a *content representation* of what that layer encodes about the photo. You do this by treating the feature maps of that layer as a desired output, and doing gradient descent on a white noise image as the input, where the loss function is the RMS between the original photo and the generated image.
3. Feed in a painting. For each conv layer you can reconstruct a *style representation* of what that layer encodes about the painting in a similar way as step 2. This time though, your loss function is the RMS between the gram matrix of all the features maps produced using a white noise input, and the gram matrix of all the feature maps produced using the painting as input. And here, you sum loss over all features maps of prior layers as well, not just the layer you are considering now.
4. Jointly minimise the loss functions described in 2 and 3 (so you're minimising *content loss* and *style loss* together) in order to produce an image with the content of the photo and the style of the painting.

**EDIT**

I have tried this. Here is an example of my results (left is input, right is output). So it's kind of cool to see some color map reduction happening, and what kind of looks like accentuation of texture, but definitely not getting these illustrated zig zag boundaries that the human mind so readily perceives as fur.

[image]

Comment: @NeilSlater I have been trying it. I'll add an edit